# How to enable div on click only to the mat-card dynamically rendering

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am working on cards , where I need to show the div containing image only to the card I am clicking. The cards I am rendering dynamically. How can I do that ?

```
<div [fxFlex]="(50/gridColumns) + '%'" fxFlex.xs="50%" fxFlex.sm="33%" *ngFor="let language of languages">
       <mat-card class="mat-elevation-z4" style="height: 60px;  border-radius: 8px;">
              <div #i style="float: right; margin-bottom: 1px">  ////== > show this div img on particular clicked card only
                    <img src ="../../assets/Images/Check.svg">
              </div>
              <mat-card-content style="text-align: center; margin-top: 23px;">
                  <span style="color: blue; font-weight: 800;
                        letter-spacing: 0.2px;">
                            {{language.content}}
                   </span>
              </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
 </div>
```

Comment: Add an `ngIf` based on a unique condition of that card? Alternatively, use `[hidden]` if you only want to hide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to manage a state in your `component.ts` file and update it on click. The index of the list can be saved as the state.
When the user clicks on the card, update the active card index.

```
@Component({})
export class YourComponent{
  currentActive = -1;

  setActiveCard(index: number){
    this.currentActive = index;
  }
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let language of languages;index as i">
   <mat-card (click)="setActiveCard(i)">
      <div *ngIf="currentActive === i">
        <img src ="../../assets/Images/Check.svg">
      </div>
      <mat-card-content>
        <span> {{language.content}}</span>
      </mat-card-content>
   </mat-card>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the correct solution , was thinking of the same but couldn't get the logic in ts file .  `currentActive = -1;` . Can you explain why -1?

Comment: That is just to initialize the variable. You could also just use `null` instead.

Comment: Got it . Thanks

Comment: Hi Adithya just a quick question. How will I make 1st card of index always active. I mean `<div *ngIf="currentActive === i">
        <img src ="../../assets/Images/Check.svg">
      </div>` will be always be checked on first index when page loads ?

Comment: Do `currentActive  =  0` in the `ts` file which makes the first index active on load.

Comment: I did that thanks.